# Confusion regarding the relation between Gibbs free energy and reaction quotient

Tags: thermodynamics

According to the Wikipedia page on the Nernst's equation, the change in Gibbs free energy is

$$ \Delta G = \Delta G^\circ + kT\ln Q \tag{1} $$

But, according to many other sources and also to my book it is given as

$$ \Delta G = \Delta G^\circ + RT\ln Q \tag{2} $$

I am confused whether to use $k$ or $R$, and also Eq. (2) doesn't make sense dimensionally ($RT$ has units of $\pu{J mol-1}$, but Gibbs free energy just has units of $\pu{J}$).

Comment: You know that $\pu{R = N_ok}$, where $\pu{N_o }$ is Avogadro number. So both formula are correct.

Comment: That is the confusion . Why don't we write R/N in the 2nd equation? Why only R?

Comment: There is no common nomenclature to distinguish molar quantities (J/mol) and extensive quantities (J). Sometime, bold typeface is used, or $\Delta_r G$. Usually, you have to infer from the context. The wikipedia article has both versions, without switching the symbol, which is confusing and not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

It's just slightly "sloppy" notation where the same symbol is used to represent different quantities.

You can understand the 1st equation as giving you the change in Gibbs free energy *per molecule* (unitless), hence the unit of $\Delta G$ and $\Delta G^\circ$ is J.

However, the 2nd equation is about the *molar* change in Gibbs free energy, ie. the change *per mole of substance*, hence the unit of $\Delta G$ and $\Delta G^\circ$ is J/mol. You could write the 2nd equation more "precisely" by including a subscript m, which is used for representing molar quantities:

$$\Delta G_{\rm m} = \Delta G^\circ_{\rm m} + RT \ln Q.$$

Comment: The [section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nernst_equation#Using_thermodynamics_(chemical_potential)) in the wikipedia article starts with "Quantities here are given per molecule, not per mole, and so Boltzmann constant k and the electron charge e are used instead of the gas constant R and Faraday's constant F.", so it is sloppy reading rather than writing.

Comment: @Karsten, I don't think I completely understand your comment :) You commented it yourself that there is no common nomenclature – and that is the point I am trying to make with my _"sloppy" notation_ explanation. I havent focused on this particular Wiki article, but on the usage in general ...